# How to automate my sources? (Python and SqlServer)

Tags: python, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, gateway

In my .pbix, my data consists of 4 queries:
[image]

One query is a     **Python.Execute**, the other 3 are **Sql.Database**.

- The SqlServer is on-prem and I already have a gateway installed there…
- The Python one is a call to an API to bring my fact table.

I want to publish it and have it updated automatically every Sunday night. What’s the standard way of achieving this?

I understand I need a PERSONAL gateway for the Python, but, where do I install it?

My laptop doesn’t seem the right place because… When the update shall run on Sunday, my laptop is going to be off.

(we have a P1 Premium capacity)

Answer (score 1):

<s>Python used in PowerQuery is only supported in Power BI Desktop. You will not be able to publish/refresh it in PBI Service.</s>

The personal gateway needs to be installed on a machine that Python will be running the scripts on. This machine will need be online for the refresh.

You can call an API natively with PowerQuery, is your script doing more than PowerQuery is able to do (advanced anayltics/transformations etc...)?

Comment: You certainly can refresh Python-components from Power BI service. It requires a personal gateway.

Comment: Thanks @Marcus - I stand corrected and have updated the answer above.